# Short Path for Ember Components

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm defining many components, which I have structured into folders.
Such as **forms/custom-button**

Always typing out

```
{{forms/custom-button}}
```

is a bit of a pain.

Is there a way define a shorter alias without changing the folders structure?